# Chrome intent link always opens an app's page in Google Play Store

Tags: google-chrome, deep-linking, deeplink, android-chrome

I am trying to make the deep link as simple as possible:

```
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=app;package=my.package.name;end;">
  Start app
</a>
```

This always starts Google Play Store to show the app page with button Open meaning the app has already been installed.

Could anyone offer a tip on how to make the link to start the app?
I am testing this with Chrome on an Android Nougat device (Acer Iconia One).

Comment: Make sure your app can handle the `app://` scheme properly

Comment: @SimonMarquis Yes, I have tested it with $ adb shell am start without any problem.  I have also tried scheme =https.   The result is the same. Tests with adb shell always succeed.

Answer (score 2):

If your definition on the android manifest is like mine:

```
`<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https"/>
 </intent-filter>`
```

You should have your intent like this:

```
`<a href="intent://example.com#Intent;scheme=app;package=my.package.name;end;">Start app</a>`
```

As you can see the difference is that if you have defined `android:host` you should also include the host in the intent definition.